# Export form in QGIS 3.8

Tags: qgis-3

In QGIS 3.8 I would like to export the code/structure of my data-forms.

I have created them via the "drag-and-drop"-surface.

[image]

Does anybody knows a solution to export it (as an xml- or ui-file)?

Comment: You can save any costumization of your data as `.qml`-file - this is true for the data-forms, too. Would this suite your needs?

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the layer properties window there's a small dropdown menu called `style`. When choosing `save style` you may save symbology, labelling, and e.g. data forms - short, any customization you did - to a `.qml` file. This file may also be used to add the customization to any other layer of the same feature type, though some things like data forms only make sense, if the attribute table of that layer has the same columns.

Pro tip: If you're lazy, you may use `set as default` in order to save all your customizations of the layer to its current storage location with one click, without having to navigate there or typing in names. Downside: This doesn't let you choose which parts of the customization are to be saved and which are to be left out.

[image]

Comment: Can Qt Designer use the qml files? it seems to only allow UI files. I want to take the form designed using the drag and drop designer in QGIS, into Qt Designer to modify it further and then bring it back into QGIS. Is this possible?

Comment: @GeorgeC this is a whole new question, I suggest you ask it separately.

Comment: done, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425638/transfer-qgis-form-from-drag-an-drop-designer-to-qt